# "Web site created using create-react-app." showing as description on all pages of my React App

Tags: reactjs

When I deploy my React site, "Web site created using create-react-app" show as the description on all pages rather than the Helmet description I have added.

I searched my entire project for "Web site created using create-react-app." and there are no results found. Where is this description coming from?

Answer (score 10):

Look in `/public/index.html`, by default on line 10 you will see:

> "Web site created using create-react-app"

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your metadata in your index.html. In your meta tag, which, as Harley Lang pointed out would be on line 10 by default, you need to change your description to whatever description you want it to be, this description is the one that will show up in search engines.